how to embed mpv video player in LiveCode standalone app
I am developing an app to generate and play a playlist of video files using LiveCode -- this is video installation artwork -- I am working on Mac. I tried to use the LiveCode player but encountered audio output problems regardless of video format I tried (played video fine but then caused very loud white noise distortion in the audio output when a video ended). I have found success by using applescript in the app to send the playlist to VLC media player. This is working great however it leaves a lot of variables outside of the control of the app itself including whether or not VLC is installed on an end-user's system, and how it might be configured. It seems VLC has rather limited AppleScript options.
The ideal solution may be to embed (imbed?) a video player app in the LiveCode standalone app and I think that it is possible to do this with mpv, however I have no familiarity with mpv and it doesn't appear that it can be controlled by applescript and I am not familar with the script languages that mpv uses.
Has anyone done this (embed mpv video player in a standalone)?
All I need it to do is to play a playlist in fullscreen, and then quit when done.
Help?
THANKS!
this was described in the previous message.
